# select the same day each month for the next 5 years using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do i select the same day each month for the next 5 years using SQL?

**eg:**

1. 05 Jan 2013
2. 05 Feb 2013
3. 05 Mar 2013

I have tried:

```
select dateadd(day,-day(dateadd(month,1,current_timestamp)) , dateadd(month,1,current_timestamp) )
```

Comment: What should happen in situations like using the 31st?  Roughly half the months don't have it.  And one month doesn't have the 30th, and the 29th rarely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '05 Jan 2013',
        @YearsAdded INT = 5

;WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT  @StartDate [Date]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH,1,[Date])
        FROM    Dates
        WHERE   DATEADD(MONTH,1,[Date]) <= DATEADD(YEAR,@YearsAdded,@StartDate)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27221)

Comment: Is it possible to do this quarterly ?

Comment: You could change the interval type from MONTH to QUARTER.

Comment: I'm trying to get the same question answered but in javascript. Can you give the answer in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect for a tally table

MONTHLY

```
--========================================================================================================================
/* tally                                                                                                                */
--========================================================================================================================

;WITH parms AS (SELECT
     YearSpan      = 5 
    ,DayOfTheMonth = 5
)

,E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)

, Tally(N) AS (
    SELECT 0 UNION
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E1 a, E1 b
)

--========================================================================================================================
/* projection                                                                                                           */
--========================================================================================================================

SELECT 
    ResultDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, DATEADD(mm, t.N, GETDATE())), (p.DayOfTheMonth - 1))
FROM parms p
CROSS JOIN Tally t
WHERE DATEADD(mm, t.N, GETDATE()) < DATEADD(yy, p.YearSpan, GETDATE())
```

QUARTERLY (uses the same "tally" code block as the MONTHLY so I've omitted the code for it)

```
--========================================================================================================================
/* tally                                                                                                                */
--========================================================================================================================

-- [code omitted]

--========================================================================================================================
/* projection                                                                                                           */
--========================================================================================================================

SELECT 
    ResultDate = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, DATEADD(qq, t.N, GETDATE())), (p.DayOfTheMonth - 1))
FROM parms p
CROSS JOIN Tally t
WHERE DATEADD(qq, t.N, GETDATE()) < DATEADD(yy, p.YearSpan, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Is it possible to do  this quarterly ?

Comment: So, the fifth day of every quarter? Absolutely. Just change the month dateparts (mm) to querter dateparts (qq). I added a QUARTERLY code block to my answer.

Comment: Sorry. That quarterly code didn't actually span five years. I did away with the math in the WHERE clause and restructured it so that the parameters are more straightforward to apply.