# How to find the same combination of the week/weekday for each month using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

Here is I'm trying to calculate the recurring dates within a range of dates. I'm pasting the code below which is only relevant to the recurrence part in my code. It has no logic of calculating the same day of each month or any pattern. It has only an interval. Please suggest a solution to find out the same day of each month from `between[]` array which already contains just a range between start and end dates.

```
switch (true) {
    case (interval == 7):
        //weekly
        //Push in the selected dates in the selected array.
        for (var i = 0; i < between.length; i += 7) {
            selected.push(between[i]);
        }
        break;
    case (interval == 30):
        //Monthly
        //Push in the selected dates in the selected array.
        for (var i = 0; i < between.length; i += 30) {
            selected.push(between[i]);
        }
        break;
    case (interval == 15):
        //Bi-Monthly
        //Push in the selected dates in the selected array.
        for (var i = 1; i < between.length; i += 15) {
            selected.push(between[i]);
        }
        break;
    case (interval == 0):
        //One time event
        //Push in the selected dates in the selected array.
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            selected.push(between[i]);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return undefined;
}
```

**Criteria to find out the next recurring date should be like this**:

> For example a user selects Wednesday from the first week of January then the next recurring date should be the Wednesday from the first week of February.

Comment: What is your definition of "*the same day*"?

Comment: exactly...every 4th wednesday vs the 22nd of each month. Criteria is not clear

Comment: @PM77-1 For example a user selects wednesday from the first week of january then the next recurring date should be the wednesday from the first week of february.

Comment: I didn't see any `Date` object created.

Comment: if you want wednesdays they occur on 7,14,21,28 intervals. Not sure what the complication is. Number of days in a week never changes

Comment: @andinugrohodirgantara I told in question that it contains the range of selected dates only. And the code above is only referring to the recurring part.

Comment: Use moment.js , save yourself a lot of time and calculating

Comment: @charlietfl Given are the two dates. start and end dates. I calculated the range between these dates. Now how can I calculate that it will be 7, 14, 21 and 28 in the next months but within the given range.

Comment: @charlietfl it has nothing to do with it. If the person who asking knows everything already, then this is not the place he is typing in then it will be his code editor. Period.

Comment: @charlietfl Please ignore if you can't help with it. Thanks.

Comment: try using `while( newDate < end Date)`

Comment: `between[]` array contains the range between those two dates. The next thing which is you unfortunately not getting. @charlietfl

Comment: but you increment until the condition turns false

Comment: @Superman: I have edited the title of your post to make it more in line with task definition. Also, it seems that in some cases the solution cannot be found, for e.g. if 1st of Feb is Monday, but the 1st of Mar is Friday (assuming that the week ends on Sunday). Thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell this is exactly what I want, thanks a lot for rephrasing it.

Comment: You are welcome. Best of luck with your project. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

#### First define selected `Date` object.

```
var between = [new Date(2015, 0, 11), new Date(2015, 0, 20)]
```

#### Now determine component that we need. They are: when is those next date should start.

```
var start = new Date(between[0].getFullYear(),between[0].getMonth(),between[0].getDate()+27)
```

it will have result the starting day in the next month and the same "day" as you describe.

#### Wrap it up to function:

```
var getNextMonth = function (date, howmany){
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+28*howmany);
};

var getNextMonthRange = function (between, howmany){
  return [getNextMonth(between[0], howmany), getNextMonth(between[1], howmany)]
};
```

#### Example

```
var between = [new Date(2015, 0, 11), new Date(2015, 0, 20)]; // Sunday, 11 Jan 2015 to Tuesday, 20 Jan 2015
var nextBetween = getNextMonthRange(between, 1); // Sunday, 8 Feb 2015 to Tuesday, 17 Feb 2015
```

I hope that is what you want :D

Comment: You explained your answer very well, I highly appreciate it. But this is not exactly what I have asked. I think my explanation is bit dubious that you do not get it right. 
**1.** I have no issues in finding the range between two dates. 
**2.** `between[]` array above in my code contains the calculated range between two dates.
**3.** Now I'm trying to find the same combination of the week/weekday for each month given in the `between[]` array. If the range contains multiple months.

Comment: Can you describe in real world problem case? Like what is variable that you already have and what are the example output that you wanted?

Comment: Please look at the log I generated each calendar is showing the each months dates. It was the case for the weekly recurrence. And it is working fine simply by looping through `between[]` array with the interval of 7 days. Now I want Monthly and Bimonthly recurring dates with this thing in mind that the first date that a user selected should be selected in next month until we completed the scan through all the dates.

http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/72efouLs/

Comment: This is the same thing I'm looking for but in javascript and within the range instead of next 5 years. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742822/select-the-same-day-each-month-for-the-next-5-years-using-sql

Comment: Wait, do you want same "day" or "date"? If I choose "Sunday, January 11 2015" next month should be "Sunday, 8 February 2015" or "Thursday, 11 February 2015"?

Comment: Same day in same week. Lets say. First week and Thursday of Jan, then First week and Thursday of Feb should be next recurring date.

Comment: So if the first date is "Sunday, 11 January 2015" The next month should be "Sunday, 1 February 2015"? Not 8 Feb right? If yes so I got it, it can be done via date object too, I will edit my answer.

Comment: No the next would be 8th of Feb. Because it should have to be the same week in next month. 11th Jan is in 2nd week that's why the next same day should be in the 2nd week of next month.

Comment: If so, just replace your `i += 30` to `i += 28` for monthly :D

Comment: Really? Wait let me check. It can't be that easy :/

Comment: There is a little problem in it. I gave start date `01/06/2015` and end date `04/23/2015` And in march it selects two dates. One is Tue 3rd of March and the second date is 31st of March. It shouldn't be the two dates in a single month.

Comment: Done. :D I restrict it to select only 1 date in a month.

Comment: And bimonthly is 14 days?

Comment: There are issues with this calculation. It do not respect the week accordingly it is simply counting the days.

Comment: Actually you should use the `Date` object. It has `date.getDay()` that return `day in a weeks` also `date.getDate()` that return `day in a month`. Combined with `Math.ceil` like `Math.ceil(date/7)` so it will return `what weeks is it`.

Comment: each element in the `between[]` array is a date object.

Comment: If so, use combination with `Math.ceil` as I mentioned before. Also try `momentjs` maybe that libs will help you a lot when playing with `date object`.